# Flutter device_info Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException

Tags: android, flutter, package

I am trying to access device info in Flutter app. It works fine on `iOS` but there is an error on `Android`.

I have added it to the `pubspec.yaml` file under dependencies:

```
device_info: ^0.4.2+6
```

and this is the code:

```
var deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  IosDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
} else {
  AndroidDeviceInfo androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
}
```

It throws an exception while calling `deviceInfo.androidInfo`:

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAndroidDeviceInfo on channel plugins.flutter.io/device_info)
```

I have tried to run `flutter clean` and uninstall the app from the device and install it again but it still doesn't work.

The result of running `flutter doctor`:

```
Flutter (Channel master, 1.21.0-10.0.pre.115)
```

I have switched to the stable channel:

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, ... )
```

but the error still happens!!

Any suggestions?!

Comment: Can you run flutter doctor?

Comment: @LapaNyAinaTanjonaRAZAFINAH I run it and everything seems to be right!!

Comment: You have used the stable channel?

Comment: @LapaNyAinaTanjonaRAZAFINAH what is the stable channel? Sorry but I am new to flutter

Comment: Can you edit your question and display the output of flutter doctor? I mean the flutter is the stable channel or not.

Comment: I have added the flutter doctor result to the question

Comment: I think you need to use stable channel instead of channel master.  
Before that, can you run this command `flutter pub cache repair` to see if the error occurs.

Comment: I think you are using latest package i.e. device_info: ^0.4.2+6 which is not suitable for yours current Flutter SDK version i.e. you need to update flutter SDK version. Better way you go with device_info: ^0.4.0+4  this version to solve yours problem. Also I have given Example bellow in Answer section please check if any doubts.

Comment: Or you can simply upgrade your Flutter SDK Version by using flutter upgrade command for latest version to solve yours problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggling I found that the reason of this issue was from `MethodChannel`. In the `MainActivity.java` file, I am defining a method channel:

```
_methodChannel = new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), "myChannelName");
```

After replacing `getFlutterView()` with `getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger()`, everything works fine.

I don't know actually the relation between them, but this is what happened.

Answer (score 2):

Try bellow example for your reference.

Before that use **device_info: ^0.4.0+4** package in **pubspec.yaml** file.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';

void main() {
  runZoned(() {
    runApp(MyApp());
  }, onError: (dynamic error, dynamic stack) {
    print(error);
    print(stack);
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  Map<String, dynamic> _deviceData = <String, dynamic>{};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> deviceData;

    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        deviceData = _readAndroidBuildData(await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo);
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        deviceData = _readIosDeviceInfo(await deviceInfoPlugin.iosInfo);
      }
    } on PlatformException {
      deviceData = <String, dynamic>{
        'Error:': 'Failed to get platform version.'
      };
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _deviceData = deviceData;
    });
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _readAndroidBuildData(AndroidDeviceInfo build) {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'version.securityPatch': build.version.securityPatch,
      'version.sdkInt': build.version.sdkInt,
      'version.release': build.version.release,
      'version.previewSdkInt': build.version.previewSdkInt,
      'version.incremental': build.version.incremental,
      'version.codename': build.version.codename,
      'version.baseOS': build.version.baseOS,
      'board': build.board,
      'bootloader': build.bootloader,
      'brand': build.brand,
      'device': build.device,
      'display': build.display,
      'fingerprint': build.fingerprint,
      'hardware': build.hardware,
      'host': build.host,
      'id': build.id,
      'manufacturer': build.manufacturer,
      'model': build.model,
      'product': build.product,
      'supported32BitAbis': build.supported32BitAbis,
      'supported64BitAbis': build.supported64BitAbis,
      'supportedAbis': build.supportedAbis,
      'tags': build.tags,
      'type': build.type,
      'isPhysicalDevice': build.isPhysicalDevice,
      'androidId': build.androidId,
      //'systemFeatures': build.systemFeatures,
    };
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _readIosDeviceInfo(IosDeviceInfo data) {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'name': data.name,
      'systemName': data.systemName,
      'systemVersion': data.systemVersion,
      'model': data.model,
      'localizedModel': data.localizedModel,
      'identifierForVendor': data.identifierForVendor,
      'isPhysicalDevice': data.isPhysicalDevice,
      'utsname.sysname:': data.utsname.sysname,
      'utsname.nodename:': data.utsname.nodename,
      'utsname.release:': data.utsname.release,
      'utsname.version:': data.utsname.version,
      'utsname.machine:': data.utsname.machine,
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
              Platform.isAndroid ? 'Android Device Info' : 'iOS Device Info'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: _deviceData.keys.map((String property) {
            return Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    property,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '${_deviceData[property]}',
                        maxLines: 10,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by excute below

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to judge the device.

```
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
}
```

Comment: I am already doing that. I just removed it in the question for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please type the entire source code that you're using? Because I've tested the library against my Android 9 and it works just fine.

Try this source code out, and it should be work.

```
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    print('Running on ${androidInfo.model}'); // e.g. "Moto G (4)"
} else {
    IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    print('Running on ${iosInfo.utsname.machine}'); // e.g. "iPod7,1"
}
```

I should also point out that if you have any issues with any flutter plugins or with flutter itself, it's best to create an issue on their repository:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins